# QGIS: special character in system user name (äöü) not showing correctly in global variable

Tags: qgis

My user name on the system (Windows Server 2016) has special characters in it, such as äöü. When opening QGIS, the global variable user_full_name does not display the characters correctly, but makes ? in boxes instead (see image).
I display the user name in a map layout, so it should be shown correctly.

[image]

I found a lot of resources online about characters not showing fine in database tables or shapefiles, but nothing concerning the global variables. I guess, the solution is simple, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Welcome to GSE ! Which version of QGIS are you using ? I create a project variable on QGIS 3.6.1 (Ubuntu) and there is no problem with special characters.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to check this answer on the very same topic (`user_full_name` and character encoding):

[QGIS general character encoding](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308894/qgis-general-character-encoding)